# Use `Promise.resolve` For Ordering Multi-function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I Have 3 Function and each one work with `Promise.resolve` Invidualy,
How Can use `Promise.resolve` For All?, When I Call All Functions, Those Aren't Ordered

```
function sendAllText(msg, opts) {
   if (locale.keyboards[msg.text].text) {
      var i,j,tempstring, promise;
      promise = Promise.resolve();
      for (i=0,j=locale.keyboards[msg.text].text.length; i<j; i++) {
          tempstring = locale.keyboards[msg.text].text[i];
          promise = promise.then(bot.sendMessage.bind(bot,msg.chat.id, tempstring, opts));
      }
   }
}
function sendAllPhoto(msg, opts) {
   if (locale.keyboards[msg.text].photo) {
      var i,j,tempstring, promise;
      promise = Promise.resolve();
      for (i=0,j=locale.keyboards[msg.text].photo.length; i<j; i++) {
          tempstring = locale.keyboards[msg.text].photo[i];
          promise = promise.then(bot.sendPhoto.bind(bot,msg.chat.id, tempstring, opts));
      }
   }
}

function sendAllVideo(msg, opts) {
   if (locale.keyboards[msg.text].video) {
      var i,j,tempstring, promise;
      promise = Promise.resolve();
      for (i=0,j=locale.keyboards[msg.text].video.length; i<j; i++) {
          tempstring = locale.keyboards[msg.text].video[i];
          promise = promise.then(bot.sendVideo.bind(bot,msg.chat.id, tempstring, opts));
      }
   }
}
```

When I call Functions, My Data is not Ordered, I'm Using Node telegram bot Api

```
bot.onText(/\/love/, function onLoveText(msg) {
  const opts = {
    reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      keyboard: [
        ['Yes, you are the bot of my life ❤'],
        ['No, sorry there is another one...']
      ]
    })
  };
  sendAllText(msg, opts);
  sendAllPhoto(msg, opts);
  sendAllVideo(msg, opts); 
});
```

Comment: You need to return the promise.

Comment: I Don't Know What Should I Do, I have 3 Type Data, Text, photo, Video, And I want to make Them Ordered send

Comment: `sendAllText().then(() => sendAllPhoto()).then(() => sendAllVideo());`

Comment: It Said `[ts] Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'`

Comment: You need to make each function return their promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of each of the three functions, right after their loops, add:

```
return promise;
```

Also make sure you define the promise variable at the start of the function, so it also is defined when the `if` condition is not true.

For example, in the first function:

```
function sendAllText(msg, opts) {
   var promise = Promise.resolve(); // <----
   if (locale.keyboards[msg.text].text) {
      var i,j,tempstring;
      for (i=0,j=locale.keyboards[msg.text].text.length; i<j; i++) {
          tempstring = locale.keyboards[msg.text].text[i];
          promise = promise.then(bot.sendMessage.bind(bot,msg.chat.id, tempstring, opts));
      }
   }
   return promise; // <-----
}
```

Then in the last piece of code, chain your promises:

```
sendAllText(msg, opts)
    .then(sendAllPhoto.bind(null, msg, opts))
    .then(sendAllVideo.bind(null, msg, opts));
```

Comment: It Said `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: Do you have the line `var promise = Promise.resolve()` at the start of the function in *each of the three* functions, *before* the `if`?

Comment: My Functions Are same as Above and i added return promise; and Called with your code

Comment: I Change my Function to this, ```function sendAllDocument(msg, opts) {
   var promise = Promise.resolve();
   if (locale.keyboards[msg.text].document) {
      var i,j,tempstring;
      for (i=0,j=locale.keyboards[msg.text].document.length; i<j; i++) {
          tempstring = locale.keyboards[msg.text].document[i];
          promise = promise.then(bot.sendDocument.bind(bot,msg.chat.id, tempstring, opts));
      }
   }
   return promise;
} ``` and called with ```sendAllText(msg, opts)
    .then(sendAllPhoto.bind(null, msg, opts))
    ```No error and no out put

Comment: I'm Sorry Solved, Because I Forget use data in my json, and my data in json was like "BQADBAADPgADYZXoUetvtS1NKJQrAg",

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$q.all](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/examples/all.js), The $q.all() method takes either an object or an array of promises and waits for all of them to resolve() or one of them to reject() and then executes the provided callback function. The values returned from the resolve function are provided depending on the way you give the promises to all().

Example -

```
var  promises = [sendAllText(), sendAllPhoto(), sendAllVideo()];

$q.all(promises).then((values) => {
    console.log(values[0]); // value Text
    console.log(values[1]); // value Photo
    console.log(values[2]); // value Video
});
```

Comment: [ts] Cannot find name '$q' and [ts] Cannot find name 'complete'

Comment: $q is a promise, So you need to use Promise instead of $q

Comment: I Added `import * as Q from 'q';`   it said Cannot find name 'complete'

Comment: Which technology you are using ?Above q lib is for nodejs

Comment: Node.js and type script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142687/discussion-between-mohan-rathour-and-sedric-heidarizarei).

Comment: I Say [ts] Cannot find name '$q   I changed to `Q.all(promises).then((values) => {` I have no error but undefined in output

Comment: use return statement in all the functions, bcz you are not returning the promise